# Ubuntu 12.04 Netinstall URL? Xen Host

Tags: ubuntu, xen, host

Well I have an Xen server, I've got a CentOS container up fine but a friend of mine wants (oh god) Ubuntu Server 12.04, why he can't use Debian is beyond my understanding. But anyways, I can't remember how I installed the CentOS container but I'm giving virt-manager a try now, since I don't have a disk image already the only option is to get a Network Install URL since I'm using PV.

So does anyone know what I should type in there, if it was CentOS I could easily type  http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.2/os/i386 for example. The furthest I've got in finding a suitable URL is http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/ but that of course wont work.

Any ideas?

Comment: An Ubuntu archive specification usually looks like this: `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse`. I don't know exactly what Xen wants though.

Answer (score 3):

Well, me being the clever person I am, I didn't set my nameservers so my server couldn't access the internet, no wonder no directory I tried worked, either way I've found it and got it working. ;)

For the reference, I used http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-i386/.

Comment: This URL did work for me. @notFound: it is okay to accept your own answer if it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you're like me, you come here every time you need to install a new Ubuntu Server in your Xen/XCP farm.  And you find that NONE of the above answers actually work.  So you use them as a base, and watch the error messages to find the actual path that needs to be entered versus the final computed path that Xen creates when it appends to what you entered.

So.... for the record, the following is what actually works:

**http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise**

Use that as your install URL when defining the new machine, and all works nicely.
Of course, if you're looking for something other than 12.04, replace 'precise' with the name of your preferred release.

Comment: Just a heads up, that URL doesn't work with libvirt as an installation location, at least not for me.

Comment: URL works when used with Citrix XenCenter.

Answer (score 2):

Mine works with:

- http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/xen/vmlinuz
- http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/xen/initrd.gz

Comment: Thanks, However, I was referring to the directory for the HTTP install via virt-install. ;)